# Gulp/Compass: How to get Compass to actually use relative paths?

Tags: sass, gulp, compass-sass, compass, gulp-compass

I have the following directory structure.

```
Gulpfile.js
--dist
--src
----config.rb
```

I'm using Gulp from the root project directory to compile my scss, which is what I think is causing issues.

When I compile (creating a sprite sheet, specifically) the URL ends up being `/src/other/stuff/here` when I need it to just be `/other/stuff/here`

You can see my config.rb here.

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "src/assets/css"
sass_dir = "src/assets/sass"
images_dir = "src/assets/images"
javascripts_dir = "src/assets/js"
relative_assets = true
output_style = :compressed
line_comments = false
```

Then in my scss file, I use the following to generate the sheet.

```
@import "icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

It creates it fine, but I just need to remove the `src` folder. I could do this with a search/replace pipe in Gulp, but I'd rather just have my config file setup properly if that's possible.

What should I look into to make this work how I need it to?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem here is.  You've placed your assets in the `src` directory and told Compass that's where they are.  So what's the problem?

Comment: I need to remove the `src` from the url path as that's not where it will actually live when it's done compiling.